# spring jackson deserialization adjust_dates_to_context_time_zone ignored

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am trying to preserve the time zone that has been passed in the REST API, I have set

```
spring:
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      adjust_dates_to_context_time_zone: false
```

Even tried using uppercase for `adjust_dates_to_context_time_zone`
But the field is always being converted to UTC:

```
@Data
@Builder
@ApiModel
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RequestDTO {

    private ZonedDateTime time;
}
```

I have even tried setting it in ObjectMapper Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false); //double kill
    }
}
```

Still the date is being converted to UTC.
At this point, I dont know what else I should try or doing wrong.
Any suggestions?

Im using Spring boot 2.4.2 and JDK 11

EDIT:

looks like this is happening, when include a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport { }
```

Comment: Actually, when you print to check it's converted into UTC I think. Can you explain how you  check data converted into UTC ?

Comment: You could get the zone by calling time.[getZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#getZone--) 
Just to be clear, I am passing the date with -03:00 timezone (this is an example) and its being converted to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration worked for me:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE); // make sure timezones are not being converted to GMT when parsing json
    }

}
```